# How to disable application pool timeout on IIS7?

Tags: iis7

On IIS6, there is a checkbox for this. On IIS7 there isn't. When the App Pool reaches its idle time, it stops. The restart is automatic, when the app is used again, however it takes 1-4 seconds to start up. This is not desirable, nor it is necessary.

Comment: I think this would be a question for ServerFault.com -- perhaps you would have gotten an answer from someone other than yourself/Google if you had asked it there.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently setting the timeout to 0 disables it: http://forums.iis.net/t/1148433.aspx